# The Infiniti MCE-5 VC-T - How does it work?

Tags: engine, engine-theory

**Is this a variable Atkinson style ICE?**

One of the new ICE platforms from Infiniti (The MCE-5 ICE) has a variable compression internal combustion engine.

The compression ratio can automatically adjust from 14.0:1 to 8.0:1.

How has Infiniti achieved this?

Is this an evolution of an Atkinson style ICE?

How quickly can the engine adjust to variables such as throttle position to produce *MOAR* power?

It seems this would have to be done at the crank with an Atkins arm that could change angles but seems extremely complex.  Although there is probably not very much data regarding reliability at this point but added complexity would seemingly reduce reliability.

Can someone provide an explicit explanation of how Infiniti has achieved this marvel of engineering?

Any visual examples to explain the process are desirable.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kV2ApRM_Pi8

Comment: @Zaid  watched a bunch of vids on it earlier so I thought I would ask the question.

Comment: @JasonC as are the answers to many questions here... With that said, [this video](https://youtu.be/9dLxHOuWErI) explains how the CR theory is applied. I'm not sure where I stand on the reliability issue - most of the mechanicals are reusing proven elements in a well-lubricated area. The downside is similar to the BMW variable lift system - what happens when the VCR solenoid fails? My guess is they've engineered a limp-mode for that inevitable scenario.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 - I'd suggest almost any mechanical failure in Infinitis system would more than likely cause catastrophic failure ... but that's my thinking.

Comment: As an aside, Wankel engines are a good example of poor reliability *not* being associated with added complexity -- on the other hand Nissan's VCR engines are using pretty run-of-the-mill components, control arms and cams and shafts and such, there's just more of them. So more things to go wrong I suppose, but at least the engineering is well-understood. We shall see. On the bright side the fundamental concept seems to be in public domain, so there's a good opportunity for competition to drive improvements in the future.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 Hm; the Nissan engine uses a [harmonic drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_drive) to move the control shaft. I did some cursory research on what happens when they fail but didn't find anything. If their failure leaves the control shaft locked then the engine should keep going with few issues, but if it lets the control shaft spin freely then it would surely make the engine unhappy. Harmonic drives seem to be renowned for reliability ([example](http://papers.sae.org/2005-01-3262/), and they like to use them to position antennas and stuff in long haul space probes too).

Comment: @JasonC Wankel engines have an inherently poor design for handling knock. The other problems were from failed oil injection. It's not the mechanical internals that caused the issues, they just suffered the consequences.

Comment: @JasonC A harmonic drive is just a gearing method. That gear still must be turned by something, i.e. a solenoid. Solenoids fail. That's what I was getting at, as it is likely the least reliable component of Infiniti's system. Otherwise while it is statistically less reliable due to the number of components, modern engineering and manufacturing has created some remarkably reliable internals in most current ICEs.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 Wankel engine primary issues were the [internal seals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3uGJGzUYCI), but that's irrelevant to the point (which was just a reflection on basic components vs. more of them). The actuation method of the control shaft ([the patent](http://pdfaiw.uspto.gov/.aiw?PageNum=0&docid=20130327302) identifies it as an "electric motor") is also irrelevant to the point (which is that what we really want to know -- to answer your question of what happens when the VCR [actuator] fails -- is whether whatever it is fails with the shaft locked or free to spin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Infiniti MCE-5 VC-T

This engine does not exist. [MCE-5 is a French R&D company](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moteur_MCE-5&prev=search) that is working on VCR engines (I *think* they're associated with Peugeot, possibly even a spin-off but don't quote me on that). Nissan (Infiniti) also worked on similar technology [independently](http://www.motoring.com.au/infiniti-launches-breakthrough-engine-tech-103185/). So there is the MCE-5 engine, the Infiniti's VC-T, Saab was working on one, Yamaha had two-stroke ones in the 90's, Lotus, Porsche, Volvo, Renault, Gomecsys, and probably a few other companies, too. But there's no "Infiniti MCE-5", which would be like a "Toyota Subaru".

> How has Infiniti achieved this?

This is pretty readily available information so I won't reproduce it fully here. However, the general gist of the VC-T (and other similar types) is that **variable compression ratios are accomplished by adjusting the stroke on the fly through various crankshaft linkages**. There are other types, for example, the Lotus Omnivore adjusts the displacement on the fly by moving the top wall of the combustion chamber ([interactive demo](http://www.lotuscars.com/omnivore-interactive-animation)), and the Gomecsys engines adjust the stroke on the fly by using [magic](https://youtu.be/PLcfNGhyAS0).

Complete details are available at:

- [Engineering Explained's YouTube video that describes Infiniti's in detail](https://youtu.be/kV2ApRM_Pi8)
- [Wikipedia page on variable compression ratio engine designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_compression_ratio#Engine_designs)
- [An article explaining that engine](http://www.roadandtrack.com/new-cars/car-technology/news/a30392/infiniti-vc-t-variable-compression-turbo/) (and [an archive link for posterity](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.roadandtrack.com/new-cars/car-technology/news/a30392/infiniti-vc-t-variable-compression-turbo/) -- not available at this very moment since the article was just recently published but I have faith that some day this link will work).
- [A 2009 article describing the technology prior to any public availability](http://www.motortrend.com/news/technologue-program-vcr/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127203312/http://www.motortrend.com/news/technologue-program-vcr/))
- [A crapload of papers on the topic](http://topics.sae.org/variable-compression-ratio-engines/papers/).
- [Nissan's US patent](http://pdfaiw.uspto.gov/.aiw?PageNum=0&docid=20130327302) (one of them, anyways).

The MCE-5 and Nissan engines are very similar except the MCE-5 [uses a piston to change the lower link's pivot point / movement range](https://youtu.be/9dLxHOuWErI?t=116), and the Infiniti uses [a rotating control shaft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9hYU2OnsfE) (you'll want to click those links). All of the VCR variants use different methods of achieving the same variable compression effect (the Lotus changed the size of the compression chamber, the Gomecsys system uses [some geared magic contained entirely within the crankshaft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnZEzJQDEl0) that they claim to be a drop-in replacement for any standard crankshaft, etc.).

> Is this a variable Atkinson style ICE?
>
> Is this an evolution of an Atkinson style ICE?

You don't *have* to use the Atkinson cycle with a VCR engine ([Saab used the Otto cycle, for example](http://papers.sae.org/2009-36-0245/)), Nissan just happens to do that.

The only difference between Otto and Atkinson is the Atkinson cycle holds the intake valves open during part of the compression stroke. According to the R&T article it switches between cycle types as needed (which is no surprise as Nissan has been pretty in to [variable valve timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-VCT) since the late 80's, which I guess was the golden age of valve timing -- VTEC came to be in the 80's, too):

> The engine's electronic valve timing and port-plus-direct fuel injection allow it to switch between normal and Atkinson cycle operation on the fly.

I suppose you could call it Miller instead of Atkinson if it's supercharged, maybe (I'm always fuzzy on these details, all I know is it's apparently super trendy to have an ICE cycle named after you). Whether you want to consider it to be an "evolution" of whatever cycle is a matter of perspective, it's merely another variant of an ICE.

It's probably worth mentioning here that this type of engine has been around for [roughly 100 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Ricardo#Aircraft_engines), but limited to lab test benches. Nissan just happened to win the public production and marketing race recently so, you know: [you go, Nissan](https://www.google.com/search?q=win&tbm=isch).

> How quickly can the engine adjust to variables such as throttle position to produce MOAR power?

Well it's all computer controlled so it can adjust immediately, limited by how fast the control shaft can rotate (Nissan), the piston can move (MCE-5), or whatever. Whether or not there's intentional delays and transitions, I don't know, you'd have to look at the ECU's firmware.

I'm positive that at the bare minimum, if there are *any* feedback loops involved, then there is at least *some* damping / filtering going on to prevent oscillations / noise in the compression ratio, and this may place some constraints on response time (although those constraints can most likely be viewed as beneficial).

> Can someone provide an explicit explanation of how Infiniti has achieved this marvel of engineering?

Yes, all of the links above as well as [all of these links](https://www.google.com/search?q=infinite%20vc-t%20engine) can provide explicit explanations with visual aids.

It's a pretty straightforward and very old concept, it's just that it took a long time for the tech to be in a state that was ready for public use. Since that just happened recently all of a sudden it's getting media attention, but there's *tons* of readily available info about these types of engines if you want to find out more.

As for reliability most of the modern variants have been under development for decades, and the first VCR prototype is about a century old. They're used in labs a lot, so they're probably off to a good start but of course there's not a lot of real-world data yet. Hopefully they don't go the way of the Wankel engine.